# "Perguntada" está mostrando hoje mas a pergunta foi feita ontem

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Fiz uma pergunta ontem mas ao entrar nela diz que foi perguntada hoje:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ele considera "hoje" até 24 horas depois de postado. No dia 16 começando em 21:26:46 passará ser ontem. Isto é uma forma de simplificar o código e a informação apresentada.

Comment: Sério? Eu jurava que às 21:00 (GMT -3) o horário já seria atualizado? Essa parte das perguntas conta 24hrs exatas após a data da postagem?

Comment: Acho estranho mostrar desse jeito. Poderia mostra as horas até completar 24 e dai em diante mostrar a contagem por dias, e assim por diante.

Comment: @Randrade até onde eu sei, sim. Olha isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown?tab=answers. Não tem hoje, mas tem as horas, ele só muda para ontem depois de 24 horas. Mas quase todos ali foi ontem (antes das 21:00)

Comment: @WendelRodrigues isso eu concordo, e como mostrei no comentário acima, tem lugar que é assim.

Comment: @bigown Agora fiquei confuso. Se você olhar [a lista de perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=4&sort=newest#question-summary-204976) verá que uma foi perguntada às **2017-05-16 12:54:08Z** e a outra **2017-05-16 12:43:00Z**, mas uma aparece perguntada 23 horas atrás e a outra perguntada ontem. Porém, a diferença entre as duas são de ~11min e ambas foram feias às 12hr, ou seja, ainda não passou mais de 24hrs. Será que é algum comportamento "inesperado" ou eu que preciso tomar mais café? kkk

Comment: @Randrade é tudo arredondamento porque vai ficando irrelevante o detalhe do horário quanto mais tempo passa. Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82278/101. Você determina qdo deve arredondar. Há 30 anos eu fiz o sistema de lista de preço pra um cliente que arredondava o valor do produto pra cima ou pra baixo de acordo com seu valor, e depois tira uma unidade tb de acordo com a escala. Então algo q custaria 1,76 de acordo com o custo e margem, passaria pra 1,79. Pra 14,72 vai pra 14,90. É mudança de escala. Qdo passa de um dia, a hora é irrelevante.

Comment: Olha agora e verá que a que estava com 23 horas agora está ontem. Passou de 24hs. O que confirma o que eu respondi.

Comment: Entendi, e realmente faz sentido. Eu acabei me esquecendo que agora são 13hrs e não 10hrs, por isso estava fazendo confusão :p

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação

Comment: @Maniero, a lógica para tratar isso já existe na ferramenta e mostrar dois conceitos diferentes no mesmo post é bem confuso mesmo! No rodapé da pergunta mostra a informação seguindo uma lógica e na lateral direita seguindo outra. [Veja essa montagem, considerando o tempo de postagem do rodape, da lateral e o horário local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtbgP.png). É o mesmo post, mesma página, mesma data de referência...

Comment: @D existe isso mesmo, mas acho que já é outro problema e parece ser algo mínimo, a não ser que eu não tenha entendido.

Comment: Vou abrir uma nova thread de bug sobre isso. _Vai que_...